# Usar expressões lambda para sofisticar os parâmetros de um for no c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

boa tarde!

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, estou desenvolvendo um código de coleta e em um determinado momento se faz necessário um for para iterar os valores da lista e logo em seguida salvar as informações em um item... Até aí tudo bem, porém o problema surge pois o frame em que estou coletando não possuí uma quantidade determinada de linhas para coleta, podendo ser de 1 linha a 50(exemplo).

Neste momento a minha lógica se quebra, pois não posso criar condições seguindo uma lógica miníma, gostaria de saber qual a possibilidade de deixar o for auto interpretativo, para quando ele passar pelos valores, as próximas linhas do array que ele ler, automaticamente ele reconheça o valor e aloque na var específica.

Acabei não postando o código pois não sei se ajudaria muito, mas segue o trecho do for e o link da página que estou capturando:

```
foreach (var acumulador in item)
{
    var texto = acumulador.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(),'Código')]/../../descendant-or-self::tr|//*[@class='RelLinhaBranca'][1]//*[contains(text(),'Código')]/../../following-sibling::tr");

    for (int j = 0; j < texto.Count; j++)
    {
        if (texto == null || texto.ToString() == "")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {

            itens.favorecido = new Favorecido() { nome = texto[j + 1].InnerText.CopyUntil("- V").Trim() };
            itens.marca = texto[j + 2].InnerText.CopyAfter("Marca").Trim();
            itens.valor_unitario = decimal.Parse(texto[j + 3].InnerText.CopyBetween("R$", "Valor").Replace(",", "").Trim(), new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
            itens.valor_total = decimal.Parse(texto[j + 3].InnerText.CopyAfter("Total").Replace("R$", "").Replace(",", "").Trim(), new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
            itens.num_item = texto[j].InnerText.CopyBetween("Código", "Categoria").Trim();
            itens.tipo_item = texto[j].InnerText.CopyBetween("Categoria", "Subcategoria").Trim();
            itens.descricao = texto[j].InnerText.CopyBetween("Descrição", "Observação").Trim();
            itens.quantidade = decimal.Parse(texto[j].InnerText.CopyBetween("Quantidade", "Tipo").Split()[1].Trim(), new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
            itens.unidade = texto[j].InnerText.CopyAfter("Cotacao").Split()[2].Trim();
        }
        documento.itens.Add(itens);
        var ex = "";
    }
}
```

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://www.comprasnet.go.gov.br/relatorios/relatorioCotacoesLicitacao.asp?txtOperacao=Consultar&intNumeroLicitacao=42207)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, uma dica, você está testando texto pra nulo mas antes dele está dando um texto.Count no for acima, se ele for nulo ele vai quebrar ali já, não depois. Mas quanto a sua pergunta, acredito que isso poderia ser resolvido com lambda usando os comandos `where` e `select`, exemplo de como ficaria:

```
var result = text.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x=> new Item()
            {

            favorecido = new Favorecido() { nome = x.InnerText.CopyUntil("- 
               V").Trim() };
              //etc

            }).ToList();
```

Isso resultaria em uma lista de items (List), então ao invés de add você provavelmente necessitaria usar AddRange

```
documento.itens.AddRange(result);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou tentar reproduzir o seu conselho e corrigir a condição de null.